# Get value of item which is clicked in datalist by Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When design I have a Datalist with a label inside. when load it will has 10 label(datasource from list has 10 value type int ). I want get value of any label which i click.  I think i must resolve 2 problem:
1. Find control(label inside datalist) which is clicked.
2. Get value of it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);

        }
        int a=1;

        DataList1.DataSource = list;
        DataList1.DataBind();
        foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
        {
            ((Label)item.FindControl("Label1")).Text = a.ToString();
            if ((Convert.ToInt32(((Label)item.FindControl("Label1")).Text)) % 2 != 0)
            {
                ((Label)item.FindControl("Label1")).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            }
            ((Label)item.FindControl("Label1")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "run();");
            a++;
        }
```

This is my run() function

```
function run() {

            $("#Panel1").scrollTop(100*gt1);

        }
```

Here, i want gt1 get value of label clicked.

Thanks for helping(sr about my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way...

We will pass the current object of label while binding javascript event with it using keyword this. on server side

```
((Label)item.FindControl("Label1")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "run(this);");
```

On Client side we have to change the definition to receive a parameter which is passed from server side. In our case parameter name is lbl.

```
function run(lbl)
{
alert(lbl.innerText);
}
```

This is nice article will give you good understanding of grid view [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18136/Edit-Individual-GridView-Cells-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: i had try it but just see .valueOf() can't see .value  and it's not work

Comment: Hi Adil, it appearance a blank popup (nothing in it), what should i do

Comment: After this ((Label)item.FindControl("Label1")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "run();"); add this ((Label)item.FindControl("Label1")).Text = "Hello Label";

Comment: text of every label is "Hello Label", if i use run(this) i see same problem(blank popup). use run() is nothing happen

Comment: Your problem is solved... Now you have to assign unique values to get unique values. This is nice article will give you good understanding of grid view http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18136/Edit-Individual-GridView-Cells-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

You can attach click event more elegantly with any item within datalist using css class instead of defining onclick event for each item.

e.g label have the following css property = "itm";

```
$(document).on('click', '.itm', function (e) {
   run(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to resolve my problem:
 
First add:

> string gt = ((Label)item1.FindControl("lblstt")).Text;

After that:

> ((Label)item2.FindControl("lblCauHoi")).Attributes.Add("onclick",
>   "run("+gt+");");

Hope it's useful.